# CheckBox setTextPosition(TOP) not working

Tags: codenameone

Windows 10 Pro
NetBeans 12.3
Simulator Latest
Simulator, IOS, Android

Setting TextPosition to TOP does not seem to have any affect, The Text is always left or right of the checkbox.

```
        Form hi = new Form("ComboBox TextPosion Test", new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        CheckBox MpiSubSystemSoon = new CheckBox("FYI");
        MpiSubSystemSoon.setTextPosition(TOP);
        hi.add(MpiSubSystemSoon);
        hi.show();
```

Assumed behavior is the Text "FYI" appears directly above the check box

Thoughts?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

This is in relation to the icon not to the checkbox which is a separate thing. This is a method of `Label` inherited by `CheckBox`.

We don't support that layout. To do that place a `CheckBox` below a `Label` in the layout.

```
CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
Container ui = BoxLayout.encloseY(new Label("My Label"), FlowLayout.encloseCenter(cb));
ui.setLeadComponent(cb);
```